# Every point in the codomain is a regular point

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $0<r<1$ and define $f:\mathbb R^3\to\mathbb R$ by $$f(x,y,z)=(x^2+y^2+r^2-z^2-1)^2-4(x^2+y^2)(r^2-z^2).$$ Let's denote $x^2+y^2=a,r^2-z^2=b$.

I don't know if this is allowed, but I just learned about the concepts of regular and singular points for a smooth map today and I hope someone could help me verify my reasoning below:

$\forall (x,y,z)\in \mathbb R^3$, $df(x,y,z)=[2\frac{\partial a}{\partial x}(a+b-1),2\frac {\partial a}{\partial y}(a-b-1),2\frac{\partial b}{\partial z}(b-a-1)]$, where $df(x,y,z)$ is a $1\times 3$ matrix and represents a map from $\mathbb R^3$ to $\mathbb R$. Assume that $df(x,y,z)=0$, then we end up with $1=-1$, therefore, every point in $im(f)$ is a regular point, since $df$ is non zero and surjective.

Comment: You neglected to take into account where the partials of $a$ and $b$ can be zero. For example: $x=y=z=0$ yields a singular point.

Comment: @BillCook Is x=0,y=0,z=0 the only singular point?

Comment: No. Choose y=0 then x=1/sqrt(2). You get a=1/2. Then choose z to make b=1/2 and you get another solution.